# DivX Player Alternative

Tags: windows-media-player, avi, wmv, divx

I have DivX but it's by far the slowest player on my WinXP netbook. It also checks for updates a crazy number of times, but I'm sure I can change that somewhere?

Is there a less resource-heavy alternative?

What file types are exclusive to DivX compared to Windows Media Player? The way I figure it, I will always have WMP for the wmv format so if it's possible to install codecs in it for all of DivX players supported files I'd do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the DivX [codecs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codec) are installed, then you should be able to view DivX media in 3rd party players like WMP.

More [info here on the DivX site](http://www.divx.com/en/software/divx-plus/codec-pack):

> The DivX Plus® Codec Pack includes everything you need to play DivX®
>   or MKV files in third-party applications, like Windows Media Player.

For a good, all-around media player that plays MANY formats without the need for extra codecs, look into the [VLC media player](http://www.videolan.org).